# NetSuite - Signature generation differs from documentation (SOAP Web Services API)

Tags: java, node.js, netsuite

I'm currently integrating with NetSuite. I am building a Node.JS integration using the token-based authentication flow.

Following the documentation, they give a series of examples for generating the base string, key, etc. I am using the provided values in a set of unit tests confirming my program correctly generates these as I compare against what the documentation provides.

Here is my issue: given a base string and key which match what the documentation says they should be, when passed in to the HMAC SHA256 hashing algorithm, my output differs. I need a sanity check, is my code correct and their documentation wrong? Or am I missing something. Regardless, I am still receiving invalid credentials, so something is wrong somewhere, regardless of whether this is correct.

Passing tests here:

```
it("Generates a base string", () => {
    const baseString = shared.exportsForTest.genBaseString(__testConfig, __docNonce, __docTimestamp);
    expect(baseString).toEqual(__docBaseString);
  });



  it("Generates a key", () => {
    const key = shared.exportsForTest.genKey(__testConfig);
    expect(key).toEqual(__docKey);
  });
```

Failing test here:

```
  it("Generates a signature", () => {
    const baseString = shared.exportsForTest.genBaseString(__testConfig, __docNonce, __docTimestamp);
    const key = shared.exportsForTest.genKey(__testConfig);
    const signature = shared.exportsForTest.genSignature({
      baseString,
      key
    });
    expect(signature).toEqual(__docSignature);
  });
```

Definition for __genBaseString:

```
function __genBaseString(config: INetSuiteConfig, nonce: string, timestamp: DateTime) {
  return _.join([
    config.accountId,
    config.consumerKey,
    config.tokenId,
    nonce,
    timestamp.toUnixInteger() // Timestamp as epoch time.
  ], '&');
}
```

Definition for __genKey:

```
function __genKey(config: INetSuiteConfig) {
  return _.join([
    config.consumerSecret,
    config.tokenSecret
  ], '&');
}
```

Definition for `__genSignature`:

```
function __genSignature({
  baseString, key
}: {
  baseString: string;
  key: string;
}) {
  const keyAsBytes = Buffer.from(key, 'utf-8');
  const baseStringAsBytes = Buffer.from(baseString, 'utf-8');

  const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', keyAsBytes)
    .update(baseStringAsBytes)
    .digest();

  return hash.toString('base64');
}
```

I've also debugged this line by line. The base string and key match the documentation inside the `__genSignature` call.

My program outputs `FCghIZqXNetuZY8ILWOFH0ucdfzQOmAuL+q+kF21zPs=` for the signature, whereas the docs output is `fzGxUBu6SZvGqv5hk8P4ou2DPthSxXtJ4zJIeCBQK5A=`

Below are the test values from the documentation. Note that these are public values provided in the docs, and in this context are not sensitive.

```
const __testConfig: shared.INetSuiteConfig = {
  accountId: '1234567',
  applicationId: '',
  consumerKey: '71cc02b731f05895561ef0862d71553a3ac99498a947c3b7beaf4a1e4a29f7c4',
  consumerSecret: '7278da58caf07f5c336301a601203d10a58e948efa280f0618e25fcee1ef2abd',
  tokenId: '89e08d9767c5ac85b374415725567d05b54ecf0960ad2470894a52f741020d82',
  tokenSecret: '060cd9ab3ffbbe1e3d3918e90165ffd37ab12acc76b4691046e2d29c7d7674c2'
};

const __docBaseString =
'1234567&71cc02b731f05895561ef0862d71553a3ac99498a947c3b7beaf4a1e4a29f7c4&89e08d9767c5ac85b374415725567d05b54ecf0960ad2470894a52f741020d82&6obMKq0tmY8ylVOdEkA1&1439829974';
const __docKey = '7278da58caf07f5c336301a601203d10a58e948efa280f0618e25fcee1ef2abd&060cd9ab3ffbbe1e3d3918e90165ffd37ab12acc76b4691046e2d29c7d7674c2';
const __docNonce = '6obMKq0tmY8ylVOdEkA1';
const __docSignature = 'fzGxUBu6SZvGqv5hk8P4ou2DPthSxXtJ4zJIeCBQK5A=';
const __docTimestamp = DateTime.fromSeconds(1439829974);
```

I've also written the program in Java, as that is what the documentation uses as examples. I wanted to eliminate any platform specific encoding issues, handling of strings etc. My Java program outputs the same signature as my node implementation:

```
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

class SignatureTestProgram {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
    SignatureTestProgram hello = new SignatureTestProgram();
    String signature = hello.computeShaHash(
      hello.getBaseString(),
      hello.getKey(),
      "HmacSHA256"
    );
    System.out.println(signature);
  }



  public String getBaseString() {
    return "1234567" + // account
      "&" +
      "71cc02b731f05895561ef0862d71553a3ac99498a947c3b7beaf4a1e4a29f7c4" + // consumer key
      "&" +
      "89e08d9767c5ac85b374415725567d05b54ecf0960ad2470894a52f741020d82" + // token
      "&" +
      "6obMKq0tmY8ylVOdEkA1" + // nonce
      "&" +
      "1439829974"; // timestamp
  }



  public String getKey() {
    return "7278da58caf07f5c336301a601203d10a58e948efa280f0618e25fcee1ef2abd" + // consumer secret
      "&" +
      "060cd9ab3ffbbe1e3d3918e90165ffd37ab12acc76b4691046e2d29c7d7674c2"; // token secret
  }



  public String computeShaHash(String baseString, String key, String algorithm) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
    byte[] bytes = key.getBytes();
    SecretKeySpec mySigningKey = new SecretKeySpec(bytes, algorithm);
    Mac messageAuthenticationCode = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
    messageAuthenticationCode.init(mySigningKey);
    byte[] hash = messageAuthenticationCode.doFinal(baseString.getBytes());
    return new String(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(hash));
  }
}
```

Comment: "Following the documentation..." - which documentation?  In [the documentation I'm looking at](https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/42019) (for TBA RESTlet authentication) you must include the HTTP method and URL-encoded base URL in the base string before signing, but I know there are different examples in the docs for different purposes (and the NS docs are a mess, but that's a different story...)

Comment: Sure! I am using the NetSuite web services platform guide. It's a nearly 400 page PDF they provided. I'll find a link.

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure I am allowed to provide the specific PDF. It was provided to me by NetSuite, but it is the "SuiteTalk SOAP Web Services Platform Guide". 396 pages and is for Version 2022 Release 2.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the baseString has proper parameters

instead of (account  consumer  key  token  nonce  timestamp)
try (httpMethod  baseUrl key  token  nonce timestamp oauth_version)

or find proper base string for your case

## Here is a working Java example - (get base string for Netsuite REST)

```
public static String getRestletBaseString(String httpMethod, String url, String consumerKey, String tokenKey,
        String nonce, String timestamp, String version, String signatureMethod) throws Exception {
    // http method must be upper case
    String baseString = httpMethod.toUpperCase() + "&";

    // include url without parameters, schema and hostname must be lower case
    String baseUrl = "";
    String getParams = "";
    if (url.contains("?")) {
        baseUrl = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));
        getParams = url.substring(url.indexOf("?") + 1);
    } else {
        baseUrl = url;
    }
    String hostname = baseUrl.substring(0, baseUrl.indexOf('/', 10)).toLowerCase();
    String path = baseUrl.substring(baseUrl.indexOf('/', 10));
    baseUrl = hostname + path;
    baseString += URLEncoder.encode(baseUrl, "UTF-8") + "&";

    // all oauth and get params. First they are decoded, next sorted in alphabetical
    // order, next each key and values is encoded and finally whole parameters are
    // encoded
    Map<String, String[]> params = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    params.put("oauth_consumer_key", new String[] { consumerKey });
    params.put("oauth_token", new String[] { tokenKey });
    params.put("oauth_nonce", new String[] { nonce });
    params.put("oauth_timestamp", new String[] { timestamp });
    params.put("oauth_signature_method", new String[] { signatureMethod });
    params.put("oauth_version", new String[] { version });

    // for (String param : (getParams + "&" + postParams).split("&")) {
    for (String param : (getParams).split("&")) {
        if (!param.isEmpty()) {
            String[] parsed = param.split("=");
            String key = URLDecoder.decode(parsed[0], "UTF-8");
            String value = parsed.length > 1 ? URLDecoder.decode(parsed[1], "UTF-8") : "";
            if (params.containsKey(key)) {
                String[] oldValues = params.get(key);
                String[] newValues = Arrays.copyOf(oldValues, oldValues.length + 1);
                newValues[oldValues.length] = value;
                params.put(key, newValues);
            } else {
                params.put(key, new String[] { value });
            }
        }
    }

    // all parameters must be sorted in alphabetical order
    Object[] keys = params.keySet().toArray();
    Arrays.sort(keys);

    String paramString = "";
    for (Object key : keys) {
        String[] valueArray = params.get(key);
        Arrays.sort(valueArray);
        for (String value : valueArray) {
            paramString += URLEncoder.encode((String) key, "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8") + "&";
        }
    }
    paramString = paramString.substring(0, paramString.length() - 1);
    baseString += URLEncoder.encode(paramString, "UTF-8");
    return baseString;
}
```